# Spreadsheet imported into SharePoint2010 List is Missing Records

Tags: sharepoint, spreadsheet

I'm migrating some old web pages into SharePoint2010 as web parts, and need to access and display existing data from an sql database.  Some of the tables have ~2300 records, so I'm hoping to avoid having to enter them individually.

I've been importing the spreadsheets using the "Create" link under the "All Site Content" page, and then selecting and importing the spreadsheets.  I've tried using varying numbers of records, from a dozen to approx. 150, and I get anywhere from ~10 to ~30 records actually added to the list.  I've formatted the headers as text and the rest of the rows as numbers.  There doesn't seem to be any pattern to which records are skipped.  The result is a list of unordered, (seemingly) random number of records.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. A co-worker was able to add the information and create list templates using the datasheet view, something that I cannot use on my machine.